# It seems "from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D" does not work anymore, how can I plot 3D in matplotlib now?

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d

I want to plot 3D in python.
All the tutorial I could find online does not work anymore, due to the deprecated `from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D`, which will return error:

```
AttributeError: type object 'Axis' has no attribute '_set_ticklabels'
```

From [matplotlib's official response on Aug. 2023](https://discourse.matplotlib.org/t/upgrade-matplotlib-installation-issues/23964), that method was removed. Then how can I plot 3D in python now? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Does this example work in your situation? https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/mplot3d/scatter3d.html

The line `ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')` sets up the 3D axis. From there you can make calls to `ax.set_zlabel()` for example.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Fixing random state for reproducibility
np.random.seed(19680801)


def randrange(n, vmin, vmax):
    """
    Helper function to make an array of random numbers having shape (n, )
    with each number distributed Uniform(vmin, vmax).
    """
    return (vmax - vmin)*np.random.rand(n) + vmin

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')

n = 100

# For each set of style and range settings, plot n random points in the box
# defined by x in [23, 32], y in [0, 100], z in [zlow, zhigh].
for m, zlow, zhigh in [('o', -50, -25), ('^', -30, -5)]:
    xs = randrange(n, 23, 32)
    ys = randrange(n, 0, 100)
    zs = randrange(n, zlow, zhigh)
    ax.scatter(xs, ys, zs, marker=m)

ax.set_xlabel('X Label')
ax.set_ylabel('Y Label')
ax.set_zlabel('Z Label')

plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: unfortunately not, it returns error "ValueError: Unknown projection '3d'", thank you very much anyway.

Comment: What version of python and matplotlib are you using? Here is are the versions that worked for me:
Python==3.10.13
matplotlib==3.8.3
numpy==1.26.4
PyQt5==5.15.10